# How to delete elements created by CreateElement and AppendChild

Tags: javascript, html, removechild

[

```js
// Calendar
var calendar = document.getElementById("calendar");

calendar.addEventListener("click",function(){

    factbox.style.bottom = "70px";
    factbox.style.transition = "0s";    
    calendar.style.transform = "rotateX(-50deg)";
    calendar.style.transformOrigin = "bottom center";
        
    var hotdogs = document.createElement("IMG");
    hotdogs.src = "SVG/hotdog2.svg";
    hotdogs.setAttribute = ("id", "hotdogs");
    everywhere.parentNode.removeChild("hotdogs");
});

// Hotdog
var hotdog = document.getElementById("hotdog");
var everywhere = document.getElementById("everywhere");
var NumClick4 = 0;
hotdog.addEventListener("click",function(){
    
    var hotdogs = document.createElement("IMG");
    hotdogs.src = "SVG/hotdog2.svg";
    hotdogs.setAttribute = ("id", "hotdogs");
    everywhere.appendChild(hotdogs);
    var x = Math.floor(( Math.random() * 450) + 800);
    
    NumClick4++;
    console.log(x + " " + NumClick4);
    hotdogs.style.width = "200px";
    hotdogs.style.left = x + "px";
    if(NumClick4 == 1) {
    
    factbox.style.bottom = "70px";
    factbox.style.transition = "0s";

    } else {
             
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="hotdog" class="">
                <img src="SVG/hotdog2.svg" alt="hotdog">
            </div>
            <div id="everywhere"></div>
   
            <div id="calendar">
                <img src="SVG/calendar.svg" alt="calendar">
            </div>
            
            <div id="factbox">
            </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrUhr.jpg)
Sorry if my code looks messy. So as shown on the image, I want the hotdogs on the sky, which were created by "CreateElement" and "AppendChild" method to disappear using "RemoveChild" method. For example, when I click other elements like "flag", I want the just the new "hotdogs" to disappear. I think I am not getting how it works. I would appreciate advice and tips.

Answer (score 1):

Following line is wrong by 2 counts

```
everywhere.parentNode.removeChild("hotdogs");
```

- You are trying to remove something which hasn't been added yet
- You need to remove the `Element` rather than `string`

i.e.

```
everywhere.parentNode.removeChild(hotdogs);
```

Comment: Even if this is technically correct, it won't help since the code that should remove `hotdogs` doesn't refer to the earlier created element, its been created with the idea that that is how to find the recently created `hotdogs`. What's needed here is to find the last child in `everywhere`, being a `hotdogs`, and delete that one. Another problem is that all created `hotdogs` have the same `id`.

Comment: @LGSon mostly agreed except the last line: *Another problem is that all created hotdogs have the same id.* Yes they all have the same `id`, but since it's `""`, it's not really a *problem*. (`hotdogs.setAttribute = ("id", "hotdogs");` won't set their `id`).

Comment: @LGSon yes sure, but this whole code is full of oddities, which was mine ;-) )

Comment: @LGSon You are right the fact that this solve all the problems that OP's code has. When I ran OP's code it gave some error telling `Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'`. My post was to explain why this is happening and how to correct the same.

Comment: Thank you everyone for trying to solve the problem. I think I need to study how "RemoveChild" works beforehand.